# How to open a custom port for the Azure Container (Swarm) agent?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-container-service

I have an Azure Container Service (Swarm). I am running a docker-compose with multiple http aspi and websites in it's definition. How can I configure the the swarm agent to allow inbound traffic to those apis? (they are running on different ports). By default I can access an api or a website under the 80 port only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By default the Load Balancer has ports 80, 8080 and 443 open.If you
>   want to connect on another port you will need to open that port on the
>   Azure Load Balancer for the Agent Pool.

There is [a document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/dcos-swarm/container-service-enable-public-access) shows you how to open more ports for your applications in Azure Container Service.

Comment: That document is not for Swarm but it works perfectly! Thank you. In case of Swarm, there was no need adding the in/out bound security group rules.

Comment: @aph5 . Yeah, as the inline said that we just need to open the port on the Azure  Load balancer . That document shows the steps for it.